Carl Polanyi's fictitious commodities
I really don't understand his concept of fictitious commodities. For example housing. Why is housing, according to Polanyi, a fictitious commodity? Why is it bad to have a housing market according to him? I myself could find many reasons, but I don't understand his argument for why this is bad. He basically just says that housing is embedded into social relations, and if you take it to a market system then these social relations don't work anymore. I really don't know what is interesting or new of this.

It's land, rather than specifically housing. Polanyi points out that land is not a product; it was there before, and nobody made it. The standard economic argument against landlords is "rent-seeking" - landlords do not actively produce anything (or do not actively produce enough to warrant their income), they merely passively benefit from their ownership of the land. So, money is going to someone who didn't do the work to produce value. This is a problem because ideally, money should motivate people to produce value for others. By the way check out https://existentialcomics.com/comic/259

See Bollier:"He describes land, labor and money as "fictitious commodities" since they cannot be multiplied and created on the market... Prior to the rise of “the market” as an ordering principle for society, politics, religion and social norms were the prevailing forces of governance. Land, labor and money itself were not regarded chiefly as commodities to be bought and sold. They were “embedded” in social relationships, and subject to the moral consideration, religious beliefs and community management."
